# How to fit column width in macro?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I wrote a macro which copies table from excel to word. In excel all columns have different width. In Word I want to fit my table to one page - margins in Word are 1.5 cm from left and right. Number of rows in my table changes, number of columns is stable (this is 14). How can I set column width to be equal? I wonder if it's possible to set the same column width regardless of the amount of text in headlines. I create swdth variable which I then divide by 14 (all my columns) and I have my table on one page...

This code doesn't work properly. I have all rows in one page, but columns have different width.

```
Table.Rows.SetHeight RowHeight:=InchesToPoints(0.17), HeightRule:=wdRowHeightExactly
Table.Rows(1).SetHeight RowHeight:=InchesToPoints(0.59), HeightRule:=wdRowHeightExactly
sWdth = InchesToPoints(6.22)
WordTable.PreferredWidthType = wdPreferredWidthPoints
WordTable.PreferredWidth = sWdth
sWdth = sWdth / 14
```

Comment: I would think the solution would be dependent on the font size and the total width of the resulting characters in each cell (in Word). If the characters are wider than the column width, the characters will wrap in the cell and increase the row height -- potentially pushing the table beyond a single page.

Comment: «How can I set column width to have all table in one page? My table has headlines with text so first row has different width.» Please be clear about what you require. You talk about *column widths*, but your code concerns only differences regarding *row heights*. *Columns* cannot span page breaks - only *rows* can.

Comment: @macropod I don't know how can I set the same column width when I have for example 14 columns. Each of them has a headline with text (shorter or longer) and I think that's is the reason why column width differs. I wonder if it's possible to set the same column width regardless of the amount of text in headlines. I create swdth variable which I then divide by 14 (all my columns) and I have my table on one page... maybe it isn't the correct way to solve my problem.

Comment: That is trivial - but you didn't ask anything about that in your question. Kindly update it. In any event, what has this to do with fitting the table height to a page? You have already fixed the row heights, so nothing you do to the column widths is going to change whether the table fits on the page.

Comment: @macropod Is it possible to set equal column width for all columns? How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Giving all columns the same with is as simple as:

```
Table.Columns.DistributeWidth
```

but it's not apparent what this has to do with keeping the table on one page.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen similar questions recently.  As always...

```
#1)  Turn on the Macro Recorder
#2)  Click through the steps you need to perform
#3)  Turn off the Macro Recorder
```

Hit Alt+F11 and you should see all the code you need to do whatever you want to do.  Remember, the Macro Recorder is your friend!